# XNA / C# - Making the Z component of a Quaternion a fixed angle value? Or is there another way?

Tags: c#, xna, quaternions

I've spent about maybe 3 hours trying to get this to work... In my developing 3D game, I already have a camera and a world matrix space. What I want to do is to make it so when you turn the camera left or right, the camera also tilts/banks left or right. However, all the methods I have tried (Slerp, making new matrix & Concatenate, setting quaternion.Z directly, etc) all failed.

Fortunately, my roll is calculated as a angle that WOULD be returned if you got the Z angle of the quaternion (It increases/decreases and goes back to 0 as you move mouse.) I'm wondering if you can set the angle for the local angle space for the camera directly with no problems. I'm inputting values between 13 and -13 which I can change to radians.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Be careful with Quanterions, their components have to be carefully kept in sync to keep their magnitude at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that your current perspective of the scene can be represented by **q_c**.  When the mouse moves to the right, you want **q_c** to begin rotating around its own **y** axis (assuming here that *y* is *up*, *x* is *right* and *-z* is *forward*) by an amount possibly proportional to the mouse displacement.  So you'll typically form a new quaternion from the axis/angle representation **q_y** = `quatFromAxisAngle(turnRate,0,1,0)`: rotate by *turnRate* around the *y* axis.  Then you apply that transformation to your quaternion to get your new perspective on the scene: **q_c'** = **q_y*q_c** (using quaternion multiplication, of course).

Now, if you want to then add some local "roll" to the perspective, you just need to do the same thing around the *z* axis, but keep a copy of the 'un-rolled' perspective: 
**q_z** = `quatFromAxisAngle(roll,0,0,-1)`
**q_d** = **q_z*q_c'**.

Then you use **q_d** to display the scene, but you throw it away afterward and always work with **q_c**.  That way, you maintain a consistent *up* axis to spin around and when you're done 'rolling' you just stop applying that final rotation around the local 'z' axis.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought of using a different quaternion to handle that stuff, haven't decided to implement it yet, but now I'm sure that your method would work.

Comment: Got a question though, would this work in exactly the same way if I were to keep the temporary quaternion? Like, I use q_d as what actually is used for the perspective, but keep q_c' too to maintain the upwards up axis?